# Proof of vertical and horizontal velocity component in projectile motion

Tags: classical-mechanics

Why is it that $v\cdot sin(x)$ gives the vertical component and $v \cdot cos(x)$ gives the horizontal component, where $v$ is the speed? What logic is there behind it, or even better is there a proof to back it up?

I know by drawing a right angled triangle you can find out the components, but I want a deeper explanation than that.

Comment: Note that those particular trig function arise from one choice of convention for measuring the angle. You are safer understanding *that* than memorizing the two formulas that you exhibit. Lest some stinker of a professor gives you a problem in which the angles are specified from the vertical or some such. Not that *I* would do that. Not me. No really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tl;dr: Vector components act like sides of a triangle, where the length of the vector coincides with the triangle's hypotenuse.

---

Mathematically, this follows from the fact that velocity in the plane is an element $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Consider a Euclidean coordinate system whose origin coincides with the spatial location of the particle in motion$^1$. Let the vertical $y$-axis be perpendicular to the ground, with increasing values of $y$ corresponding to an increasing altitude. In the standard orthonormal basis,

$$ v = v_x e_x + v_y e_y,$$

where $v_i = v \cdot e_i$. Defining $\theta$ as the angle between $e_x$ and $v$, it follows that the dot product gives

$$v_x = ||v|| ||e_x|| \cos \theta = ||v|| \cos \theta .$$

Determining $v_y$ is fairly simple as well. Because $e_x$ and $e_y$ are orthogonal, it follows that the angle between $v$ and $e_y$ is $\pi / 2 - \theta $. Using the dot product gives

$$v_y = ||v|| ||e_y|| \cos (\pi / 2 - \theta) = ||v|| \sin \theta .$$

It should now be apparent that talking about $v_x$ and $v_y$ is only meaningful when one has defined a coordinate system. They are arbitrary, and and any orthogonal coordinate system is equally valid in defining the velocity's components. In the case of projectile motion relative to flat ground, it is *convenient* to the coordinate system as defined above.

1. I have disregarded the fact that $v$ is technically a "free" vector with no position, but this is irrelevant for our purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Practically also we can explain it.……Consider a plane or a table top.An object is placed at one of its edge.Now when we push the object perpendicular to the edge it will move in the direction of applied force i.e perpendicular to the edge of table top with velocity  v0 for example.……………………………………………………
Now we take another force which is parallel to that edge.This force wont counteract the other force because it is perpendicular to its direction.……………………………………………When this force also acts we would find for one unit distance travelled by object in this direction one unit distance has also been travelled by the object in direction perpendicular to the edge of table.Velocity is same for same force given here…………………………………………Now by triangle law of vector addition we Add the displacement and would find net displacement from the original position of the object on the table top to the head of displacement in direction perpendicular to edge which is final position.Let this diplacement be x.Now this displacement and displacement perpendicular and parallel to the edge of table top forms a right angled triangle in which x is the hypotenuse.xsin45° is displacement perpendicular to edge and xcos45° its displacement parallel to edge of table top.……………………1.since force is same for the object,velocity is same,therefore distance per unit time is same which i have taken unit distance.Since unit distance is same angles other than 90° are 45° and 45°.

Comment: The same thing can be done for other displacement,therefore other angles.